# Add weekday sequentially from one-hot encoded input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a sparse weekday format, sequentially representing week days, adding contextual information from an additional list;

to illustrate:

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

print(df)

 employee_name  rest_day
      Alex          0
      Alex          0
      Alex          0
      Alex          0
      Alex          0
      Alex          0
      Alex          1

      Frank         1
      Frank         0
      Frank         0
      Frank         0
      Frank         1
      Frank         0
      Frank         0
...
```

In which Alex takes a rest on Sunday and Frank on Mondays and Fridays.

I'd like to add a new column, with values from the aforementioned list, indicating weekday as:

```
print(final_df)

 employee_name  rest_day   weekday
      Alex          0       Monday
      Alex          0       Tuesday
      Alex          0       Wednesday
      Alex          0       Thursday
      Alex          0        ...
      Alex          0
      Alex          1       Sunday

      Frank         1       Monday
      Frank         0         ...
      Frank         0
      Frank         0
      Frank         1
      Frank         0
      Frank         0       Sunday
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `date_range` for getting week day name, more intuitively

```
from itertools import cycle

seq = cycle(pd.date_range('2021-05-24', '2021-05-30').to_series().dt.day_name().to_list())
df['day'] = [next(seq) for count in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Output

```
   employee_name  rest_day    weekday
0           Alex         0     Monday
1           Alex         0    Tuesday
2           Alex         0  Wednesday
3           Alex         0   Thursday
4           Alex         0     Friday
5           Alex         0   Saturday
6           Alex         1     Sunday
7          Frank         1     Monday
8          Frank         0    Tuesday
9          Frank         0  Wednesday
10         Frank         0   Thursday
11         Frank         1     Friday
12         Frank         0   Saturday
13         Frank         0     Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each `employee_name` has exactly 7 rows, you can use:

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

df['weekday'] = df.groupby('employee_name').transform(lambda x: weekdays)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   employee_name  rest_day    weekday
0           Alex         0     Monday
1           Alex         0    Tuesday
2           Alex         0  Wednesday
3           Alex         0   Thursday
4           Alex         0     Friday
5           Alex         0   Saturday
6           Alex         1     Sunday
7          Frank         1     Monday
8          Frank         0    Tuesday
9          Frank         0  Wednesday
10         Frank         0   Thursday
11         Frank         1     Friday
12         Frank         0   Saturday
13         Frank         0     Sunday
```